# Update Command in Datagridview to database

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

i've been working so far with my database issue, i can't proceed with a new module for the reason that i can't update my database through datagridview

can somebody check on my codes why i can't update my database in datagridview using a button click?

here's how i had my datagrid content:

```
Public Sub loaddgvfrm3()
    cmdconn = New SqlConnection
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmdconn.ConnectionString = sqlstr
    cmdconn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn
    cmd.CommandText = "select  period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated, claim_no,  year_student from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + txtClaimno.Text + "'"
    'cmd.CommandText = "select  a.period, a.VOUCH_AMT, a.INDIVIDUAL_AMT, a.check_no, a.bal_ent, a.D_MAILED, a.DIR_NO from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY a left join carlos.claims_waivee b on a.CLAIM_NO = b.claim_no where b.CLAIM_NO like '" + claimno.ToString + "'"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
    cmdconn.Close()
End Sub
```

now i want to modify some rows within that datagridview and update changes that i made into database with a buttonclick

here's my button click code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click


    Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand

    Try
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connstr)
            connection.Open()
            cmd2.CommandText = "update tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY set period=@period, vouch_amt=@vouch_amt, individual_amt=@individual_amt, check_no=@check_no, d_mailed=@d_mailed, dir_no=@dir_no, who_updated=@who_updated where claim_no = '" + txtClaimno.Text + "' "

            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@period", SqlDbType.Char, 25, "period")
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@vouch_amt", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Precision = 18, .Scale = 2}).Value = "vouch_amt"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@individual_amt", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Precision = 18, .Scale = 2}).Value = "individual_amt"

            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@check_no", SqlDbType.Char, 15, "check_no")
            'cmd2.Parameters.Add("@d_mailed", SqlDbType.DateTime, "d_mailed")
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@dir_no", SqlDbType.Char, 15, "DIR_NO")
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@who_updated", SqlDbType.Char, 15, "who_updated")
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
            MsgBox("changes done")
            'MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully!", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    msgbox(ex.message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

the problem that occur "executenonquery : connection property has not been initialized"
what could be the problem of mybutton save?(i don't know if im doing things right, did i connect these two "subs" correcty?) if you have any other suggestion on (updating) the changes i made in the datagridview pls. feel free to modify the save button :(

Comment: put breakpoint in `Catch` block, run your application in debug mode. If it goes to `Catch`, dig into `ex` to gain as much info about what causes the exception. Or at least, put `MessageBox.Show("Something")` in `Catch` block to get notified whenever exception occur

Comment: i got that updated. executenonquery: connection property has not been initialized. thats the error. is my savebtn sub is somehow connected to the loaddgvfrm? :(

Comment: based on the error message, it seems that you missed single line. Check my answer :) About 2nd question : nope. Given all variables declared locally inside sub, both subs are not connected in anyway

Comment: how can i connect the two subs? to make the button function work with the datagridview?

Comment: thanks. now the new error is that "failed to convert parameter value from a string to a decimal. what could be the error now? :/

Comment: parameter `@vouch_amt` declared as Decimal type, but assigned value of type string ("vouch_amt")

Comment: how can i assign that "vouch_amt" to decimal?

Comment: simply put in decimal/number value instead of string?

Comment: oh no. is that so? cuz what im trying to do is modify the selected row in the datagridview, and then update it to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to set `Connection` property of `cmd2`. Simply add this line after `connection.Open()` :

```
cmd2.Connection = connection
```

**UPDATE :**

You can try using `DataAdapter`'s `Update()` function passing DataTable as parameter to commit changes from DataTable to database :

```
da.Update(dt);
```

[[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]

Comment: i did that before but somehow, i can't find any solution on how to link the loaddgv sub and the btnsave sub. that is what im trying to find right now.

Comment: If I understand what you mean by *linking* loaddgv sub and btnsave sub correctly. My update above means, you can submit changes in DataTable (which is data source of your DGV) back to database that way. Put that line of code inside btnsave sub, and given `dt` is global variable (declared outside sub), then both subs are *linked* now (operating against same instance of DataTable).

Comment: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows. thats the new error

Comment: just to give u a heads up, im not doing any dataset commands. cuz it quite confuses me more. i'm new in vb.net :(